# Lighttpd Proxy -> Apache SVN mod_dav_svn - Stuck via command line but works in browser

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, svn, lighttpd

I have a confusing problem. I have installed a long time ago Apache 2.4 with mod_dav_svn to be able to access my repos via https urls. It all works fine with Apache only. Now i switched to lighttpd and i've managed the access via https now with a `proxy.server` in my lighttp config. This work fine in the browser, i can still access my repos via the browser right now. But, now it doesn't work with command line or tortoise svn anymore. It hangs infinitely. There's no error in the log or something, it just hang without errors. When i cancel the request in the command line than it says `unable to connect...` but when i enter the same url in the browser it works perfectly. I don't have any idea how to fix this.

Edit: If i disable SSL on the lighttpd side and pass it via port 80 than also it does not work. It ask for username and pass, than it hangs.

Here is my lighttpd config

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
    ssl.engine = "enable",
    server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/ssl-error.log",
    ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/owncerts/defaultcert.pem",

    HTTP["host"] == "myhost.com"{
        server.document-root = "/srv/default/htdocs",
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/owncerts/myhost.com.pem",
        proxy.server = (
            "" => (("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8443))
        )
    }
}
```

And here is my apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    ServerName https://myhost.com
    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /srv/svn/xxx
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "xxx SVN Repository"
        AuthUserFile /srv/svn/xxx/conf/users
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /srv/svn/xx/conf/authz
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**TEST 1**

When i do a OPTIONS request check via `curl` than i give me a correct output like this - Both in Apache and Lighttp access log there are response codes with "200".

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Mar 2015 13:07:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
DAV: 1,2
DAV: version-control,checkout,working-resource
DAV: merge,baseline,activity,version-controlled-collection
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/depth
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/log-revprops
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/atomic-revprops
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/partial-replay
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/inherited-props
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/inline-props
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/reverse-file-revs
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/mergeinfo
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Allow: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST,DELETE,TRACE,PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,COPY,MOVE,LOCK,UNLOCK,CHECKOUT
Content-Length: 0
```

**TEST 2**

If i do a simple "checkout" request via svn command line than the following happens

This requests are on the lighttpd side

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx myhost.com - [09/Mar/2015:14:13:19 +0100] "OPTIONS /testrepos HTTP/1.1" 401 588 "-" "SVN/1.8.11 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.8"
```

This request are on the apache side

```
myhost.com:443 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2015:14:13:19 +0100] "OPTIONS /testrepos HTTP/1.0" 401 825 "-" "SVN/1.8.11 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.8"
myhost.com:443 127.0.0.1 - brain [09/Mar/2015:14:13:19 +0100] "OPTIONS /testrepos HTTP/1.0" 200 1661 "-" "SVN/1.8.11 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.8"
```

At this point the svn command line client hangs.

**TEST 3**

If i do a simple OPTIONS request with CURL on a existing repos (testrepos), it works as expected

Here is the lighttpd log

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx myhost.com - [09/Mar/2015:14:30:41 +0100] "OPTIONS /testrepos HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
```

Here is the apache log

```
myhost.com:443 127.0.0.1 - brain [09/Mar/2015:14:30:41 +0100] "OPTIONS /testrepos HTTP/1.0" 200 855 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
```

**TEST 4**

Unfortunetely i cannot debug my svn client's network connection, there is no such option anymore in 1.8. Furthermore i've tested it without any Basic Authentication. Also not working, both Apache and Lighttpd return 200 response codes but the SVN CLI client still hangs. When i try checkout the URL directly on the apache side with `http://myhost:8443/testrepos` it works also with the CLI client. It seems that the proxy pipe between Apache and Lighttp is broken. I probably will decide to skip my error search progress and switching my repos just to the new port instead of the default ssl port. It requires some work for me but it finally will work.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Added the output log to post

Comment: @AndréDaniel Done, and added also more debug information

Comment: Can you do the `OPTIONS /testrepos` in curl and see what appears in the Lighttpd log ? It's strange that despite Apache replying 200 on the second (authenticated) request, there is no mention of it in Lighttpd's log. Looks like Lighttpd for some reason fails to return the response of the second request.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Added it to the post, it all works perfectly in CURL and Browser, but not via svn CLI. svn cli tested on the server itself and on my local windows machine, both same hang error.

Comment: Enable verbose output for the SVN command and see where it fails, more info : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13823619/2629998

Comment: By the way, upvoted just because you provide the requested info in a timely manner, something that sadly became quite rare here.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Thx, added new infos to topic. I decide to stop error debugging right now, it seems there is no end. I will take the faster way and use directly the apache urls with the port number in it, this work just fine. More info in topic "TEST 4". Anyway, thx for your help.

Comment: I have hit the same problem. Trying to troubleshoot it with mitmproxy, it looks like one of the requests of the svn client is never seen by the Apache server. I suspect a possible problem with lighttpd's mod_proxy. As this is too complicated to troubleshoot, however, I'll also move to a different solution.